# Отрисовка компонентов из библиотеки vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Я пытаюсь разбить компоненты по отдельным файлам, чтобы потом собирать их в одном компоненте и отрисовывать.
main.js выглядит так:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import './vuetify/vuetify.min.css'
import top_menu from './top-menu/top-menu.vue'

Vue.component("top-menu", top_menu)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

App.vue выглядит так:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app id="inspire">
      <top-menu></top-menu>
    </v-app>
  </div>
</template>
```

В консоль выводится ошибка: Property or method "$vuetify" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property

Почему библиотеку не видно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**main.js:**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App";

import Vuetify from "vuetify";
import "vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css";
Vue.use(Vuetify);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: { App },
  template: "<App/>"
});
```

**App.vue:**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <v-app id="inspire">
      <top-menu></top-menu>
    </v-app>
  </div>
</template>
```

**P.S:** Вы пропустили `Vue.use(Vuetify);`

[Vueyify должно быть обязательно установлено!](https://vuetifyjs.com/ru/getting-started/quick-start)

Пример простейшего vue app с vuetify [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/nw6kjyy92m)

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение, сейчас буду пробовать